# How to select files in a directory begins with explicit names in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script as below

```
dcacheDirIn="/mypath/"
for files in `ls $dcacheDirIn | grep txt`
do
.....
done
```

I have some .txt files in this directory, some of them begins with Data2012*.txt and some of Data2011*.txt. How can I choose "Data2012" files?

EDIT: my bad I mixed up with my python file. This is shell script for sure.

Comment: How sure are you this is python?

Comment: @melwil pretty sure :)

Comment: This is absolutely not Python. Maybe bash script?

Comment: Certainly looks like bash!

Comment: why dont you grep `Data2012` to get `Data2012` files?

Comment: @itzmeontv yours thebest and for dummies answer.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
dcacheDirIn="/mypath/"
for files in `ls $dcacheDirIn | grep Data2012`
do
echo $files
done
```

To avoid directories with that name, try

```
ls $dcacheDirIn -p | grep -v / | grep Data2012
```

Comment: How can i choose Data2012 files then?

Comment: that loop exists only files with name contains `Data2012`

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can use the `glob` library as follows:

```
import glob

for file2012 in glob.glob("/mypath/Data2012*.txt"):
    print file2012
```

Tested using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

The python `glob` library has that capability and it also supports regex expressions. So, for instance, you would do:

```
for file in glob.glob('*2012.txt'):
    print file
```

and that would print the files matching that expression (assuming you're running it from the same directory). It has a heap-load more functionality though, you should dive deeper.

Edit: fixed indents, need more chars..

Comment: Sorry about the indenting issues, I'm mobile and it isn't kind.

Comment: Thanks @melwil. Too bad my answer is irrelevant now :(

Comment: Hey, not your fault. And no worries ;-) Props for even doing it on a mobile device!

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep to achieve this directly:

```
dcacheDirIn="/mypath/"
for files in `ls $dcacheDirIn | grep -E 'Data2012.*\.txt'`
do
.....
done
```

`grep` uses regex to filter the output from `ls`. The regex I provided for grep will filter out files in the format `Data2012*.txt`, like you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

In bash the wildcards will do the work of ls for you. 
Just use

```
dcacheDirIn="/mypath"
for file in $dcacheDirIn/Data2012*txt
do
   echo "File $file"
done
```